# array access from inside a class in java

Tags: java

Assuming whe have 8  instances of a class and 8 arrays outside the class. Something like:

```
float[] t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8;


public void myclass{
```

How can we access the array fields from inside the class?
So that the first instance of the class corresponds to the first array "t1"
the second to "t2" etc.

```
}

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        classID[i] = new myclass(i);
    }
```

Comment: There is no 'outside the class' in java :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "8 arrays outside the class"? Those arrays have to be somewhere. Where they are will dictate how/if you can access them.

Comment: The class should be constructing the `float[]`. I would use `double[]` unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: in java, how can we have some array outside the class ? isnt this must be inside some class ?

Comment: It is not clear for me. How many classes do you have? If this is the only one then you cannot have an array outside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**in Java,** if it is out side of class it should be in other class, so you need object of that class to access that array

```
class Foo{
  private int arr[];
  public int[] getArr(){
    return this.arr;
  }
}
//from other class now

new Foo().getArr();
```

or else it needs to be static

```
class Foo{
  public static int arr[];
}

//from other class
int arr[] = Foo.arr;
```

Comment: You are welcome (also don't forget to upvote & accept, if this is **actually working**  answer for you) :)

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of class should contain one array. The array can be passed in the constructor, like this:

```
class MyClass {
    private float[] t;

    public MyClass(float[] aT) {
        t = aT;
    }
}
```

Then, when you create your instances, pass appropriate arrays to constructor calls:

```
MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass(t1);
MyClass myClass2 = new MyClass(t2);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean?

```
MyClass[] arrays = new MyClass[8];
for(int i=0;i<arrays.length;i++) arrays[i] = new MyClass();


class MyClass {
    final double[] values = new double[10];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare an ArrayList of float arrays like

```
ArrayList<float[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<float[]>;
```

Then add each of your arrays to the arrayList. Each class will access arrayList.get(i).

Answer (score 0):

**There is no 'outside the class' in java** So
what i get u.. is  u have a class in which there is 8 `Float` type Array  u made 8 different instance of your class ..
And through each Object  u want to access a different Object because "sequence of object is depend on sequence in which they are instantiated    "
**So for that :-**
U can make a int counter as `static` and every time in the constructor of class u increment the counter and store that value . And access Array of respected value of counter..